# MongoDB Complex Stages Query With different Results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, jsoniq

I'm trying to find a Query Language for our product team, so they can create "red-flags" based on complex queries of a collection.
as they are not familiar with code, i've tried looking at JsonIQ solution but it seems it's un-maintained and couldn't find a simple solution to MongoDB.

So they a simple alternative? can mongo "stages" query accomplish something like the following example (if so, how?)

`itemCount = number of total contributionItems
if itemCount>5
   foreach item 
     if (number of items with the same party)/itemCount>0.8
        save that party as party1
        PH1=party1
        for each contributionItem if (contributionItem.party != party1)
            add item to array.
             PH2=array[item.party]`

Comment: it's not clear, can you add sample documents from your collection, and the expected output?

Comment: Why unclear? Let's say i have an "items" table, which has different types.    
This is the begining  // Pipeline
 [
  // Stage 1
  {
   $match: {
    "type": "ContributionItem",
    "searchId": 146
   }
  },

  // Stage 2
  {
   $count: "count"
  },

  // Stage 3
  {
   $match: {
       count: { $gt: 5}
   }
  },

 ]

Answer (score 0):

JSONiq, as a language, is alive and maintained. The specification is not updated often because it is stable. There are a few implementations available documented on the [language website](http://jsoniq.org/) and these may vary over time (I am unsure if any currently supports MongoDB specifically though).

A JSONiq version of your query, as I understand it, would look like:

```
let $contribution-items := collection("contribution-items")
let $count := count($contribution-items)
where $count gt 5
let $party1 :=
    for $item in $contribution-items
    group by $party := $item.party
    where count($item) gt (0.8 * $count)
    return $party
where exists($party1)
return [ $contribution-items[$$.party ne $party1] ]
```

Comment: Thanks- that sounds good -but still how will i overcome the gap with Mongo / Mongoose?